# Erro Notice: Trying to get property of non-object ao pegar o titulo da pagina

Tags: php, html, http, parâmetros

estou com um codigo que deve pega o titulo da pagina exemplo "Facebook – entre ou cadastre-se" só que está dando erro nessa linha

```
$title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item('0')->nodeValue;
```

esse é o codigo:

```
function website_title($urli) {
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urli);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// define um usuário agente.
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36');
   $html = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   $dom  = new DOMDocument;
   @$dom->loadHTML($html);

   $title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item('0')->nodeValue;
   return $title;
}

echo website_title('https://www.facebook.com/');
```

se alguém puder me ajudar fico grato.

Comment: Faz um `print_r( $dom->getElementsByTagName('title'));` coloca ai o resultado.

Comment: ok pera ai vou testar

Comment: apareceu esses erros: <pre>Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ... line 143</pre>

<pre>Notice: Undefined variable: dom in .......... line 143</pre>

<pre>Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on null in .............. line 148 </pre>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você possui alguns erros em seu código, o primeiro dele é - Nunca use `@` para suprimir mensagens de erro, isso faz seu código ficar mais lento e difícil de debugar. Se não tivesse colocado o `@` saberia o motivo da sua dificuldade.

Segundo, o seu problema em especifico é o seguinte: Você não esta passando ao método `loadHTML()` nenhum valor, basicamente sua variável `$html` esta vazia. Isso aconteceu por um motivo, o seu código cURL não levou em conta que o Facebook utiliza `https` e por isso a requisição cURL falhou, desencadenando todo o problema. O código abaixo mostra uma versão funcional de seu código.

```
<?php

function website_title($urli) {
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urli);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
// define um usuário agente.
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36');
   $html = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   $dom  = new DOMDocument;
   $dom->loadHTML($html);


   $title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item('0')->nodeValue;
   return $title;
}

echo website_title('https://www.facebook.com/');
```

Eu já [fiz uma biblioteca](https://github.com/renatotavares/curl) para facilitar o uso do cURL, ele é muito simples, mas pode te ajudar .

Comment: entendi muito obrigado estava tendo esse erro por causa do site do facebook a forma que eles utiliza o titulo das paginas.